# How to use constants to determine line of text from URL to be printed

Tags: java, url

So in the URL string at the beginning, in each of those URL, there are many lines of text displayed on each website. I need to find a way to determine which lines of text have the timezone and datetime values that I need. The TIMEZONELBL and DATETIMELBL constants are supposed to help me pass these lines. However, I am stuck on this. The code is in Java. I am somewhat new to code so bare with me!

```
public class Main {
    private static final String[] urlList = { 
            "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/London.txt",
            "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/America/New_York.txt",
            "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/America/Chicago.txt",
            "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/America/Los_Angeles.txt",
            "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Tokyo.txt",
            "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Australia/Sydney.txt" 
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("=== Current Date/Times Around the World ===");
        try {
            for (String url : urlList) {
                System.out.println(extractCurrentTimeInfo(url));
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static String extractCurrentTimeInfo(String urlstr) throws IOException {
        
        final String TIMEZONELBL = "timezone: ";
        final String DATETIMELBL = "datetime: ";
        String timezone = null;
        String datetime = null;
        String result = "error";
        URL url = new URL(urlstr);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        
        // TODO - add code here
        
        return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything else works (Reading the content of the URL)

You can read the text line by line and use [startsWith](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_startswith.htm) method to see if any of the string matches `TIMEZONELBL` or `DATETIMELBL`

Also looks like your method returns only one string. But you are looking for timezone and datetime. You might want to change the method signature to return a Object or a array that holds 2 values.